# Android - Jelly Bean page freeze on html page transition

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an web application, On form submission i wish to show loading image until the next page loads,the issue is with Jelly Bean, it Simply freezes the page 1, after some time it loads the page 2, loader is not at all showing 
I tried blockui.js, show/hide div on form submission but no Expected result.
I don't find this issue in other android versions like Gingerbread and ICS.

Note: When i delay my form submission, it shows the loader image.

Answer (score 0):

I think in jelly bean There is a change in web-kit. JB uses the web-kit of chrome. That's why the app runs smoothly on all other versions and it becomes weird when it comes to Jellybean. you need to manage it it any other ways. I also faced somewhat a similar problem when I had done an application compleatly based on html and js. Still i was not able to complete this problem and i need to drop the app due to kind of reasons